# Winsock with C# Severity Code ERROR: The name 'DataInput' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, server, client, winsock

I'm new to coding in c#,My Project is connecting server and client using Winsock control. I am doing exactly this program http://www.go4expert.com/articles/winsock-c-sharp-t3312/ to connect server and client.

form:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRu7C.png)

code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Winsock
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.w1.Error += new AxMSWinsockLib.DMSWinsockControlEvents_ErrorEventHandler(this.w1_Error);
            this.w1.ConnectEvent += new System.EventHandler(this.w1_ConnectEvent);
            this.w1.DataArrival += new AxMSWinsockLib.DMSWinsockControlEvents_DataArrivalEventHandler(this.w1_DataArrival);
        }
        Boolean isConnect = false;
        private void w1_ConnectEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataInput.Text += "\n - Connect Event : " + w1.RemoteHostIP;
            isConnect = true;
        }

        public void w1_Error(object sender, AxMSWinsockLib.DMSWinsockControlEvents_ErrorEvent e)
        {
            DataInput.Text += "\n- Error : " + e.description;
            isConnect = false;
        }

        private void w1_DataArrival(object sender, AxMSWinsockLib.DMSWinsockControlEvents_DataArrivalEvent e)
        {
            String data = "";      
            Object dat = (object)data;
            w1.GetData(ref dat);
            data = (String)dat;
            DataInput.Text += "\nServer - " + w1.RemoteHostIP + " : " + data;
        }

        private void send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (isConnect)
                {
                    w1.SendData(SendText.Text);

                    DataInput.Text += "\nClent(You ;-) : " + SendText.Text;

                    SendText.Text = "";
                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show("You are not connect to any host ");
            }
            catch (AxMSWinsockLib.AxWinsock.InvalidActiveXStateException g)
            {
                DataInput.Text += "\n" + g.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DataInput.Text += "\n" + ex.Message;
            }
        }

        private void disconnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            w1.Close();
            w1.LocalPort = Int32.Parse(portText.Text);
            w1.Listen();
            DataInput.Text += "\n - Disconnected";
        }

        private void Connect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                w1.Close(); 
                w1.Connect(IPText.Text, portText.Text);

            }
            catch (System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.InvalidActiveXStateException g)
            {
                DataInput.Text += "\n" + g.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void w1_ConnectionRequest(object sender, AxMSWinsockLib.DMSWinsockControlEvents_ConnectionRequestEvent e)
        {
            if (isConnect == true)
            {
                w1.Close();
            }
            w1.Accept(e.requestID);
            isConnect = true;
            DataInput.Text += "\n - Client Connected :" + w1.RemoteHostIP;
        }
    }
}
```

Error

> The name 'DataInput' does not exist in the current context

I can't seem to find a solution to this problem by searching the web Please help me :(

Comment: It appears that DataInput is the name of the edit control used for the send data. You likely named it something else on your form.

Comment: @JamieMeyer sorry i'am unable to understand "something else" means what i need to use instead of DataInput.

Comment: I looked at the code again. The large control below the label "Get Data" should be named DataInput.

Comment: @jamieMeyer Thank u for that valuable command it shows the data that connect and it gives the the data what i enter in client side ( see screen short in my question)but please tell me how i use server form . if i need to create new form ? or i use bin->debug->server.exe? but it not works i try that . please tell me how i access the server form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Textbox Named "DataInput" on your form.